# How private document directory can be set in iOS8 as storage provider application extension is making default Document directory Shared?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension

My iOS app is running all well & good till iOS7. But as soon as I run on iOS8 beta version it crashed.
When I tried to investigate I found that in iOS8 Storage provider changed the path for the default document Directory.

How can I set it to default Document directory to keep the applications private data Safe

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the path of the Documents directory? If you use the recommended API (like below) it should translate over to ios8 without any problems.

```
NSString *docsDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
```

Also, not clear what you mean by "keeping private data safe" -- any data you write to the Documents directory is not accessible by any other app.